# Java convert json rest api response to image

Tags: java, json, image, rest

I am connecting to a third party rest application (with limited documentation) and one of the requests returns a jpeg.  I normally use an `ObjectMapper` to convert the json response to an object which works fine but I don't know how to convert the following response to an image:

```
10:18:29.885 [main] DEBUG org.apache.http.headers - http-outgoing-0 << HTTP/1.1 200 OK
10:18:29.885 [main] DEBUG org.apache.http.headers - http-outgoing-0 << Cache-Control: no-cache, must-revalidate
10:18:29.885 [main] DEBUG org.apache.http.headers - http-outgoing-0 << Content-Length: 25001
10:18:29.885 [main] DEBUG org.apache.http.headers - http-outgoing-0 << Connection: close
10:18:29.885 [main] DEBUG org.apache.http.headers - http-outgoing-0 << Content-Type: image/jpeg
10:18:29.885 [main] DEBUG org.apache.http.headers - http-outgoing-0 << Date: Thu, 27 Jul 2017 09:18:29 GMT
10:18:29.897 [main] DEBUG org.apache.http.wire - http-outgoing-0 << "[0xb1][0xe7][0x8b][0x2][0xdb]K[0xe][0xde]c[0xf1][0x9c][0xff][0x0]t`z[0xe7][0x9a][0xda]{{Ym[0xd6][0x1f]*?%W[0x8][0xaa][0x0][\n]"
10:18:29.897 [main] DEBUG org.apache.http.wire - http-outgoing-0 << "=[0xb1][0xd3][0xf0][0xaa][0x1]"[0xd3][0xad]m[0xe1]x[0x84]~`[0x94][0xee][0x95][0xe5];[0x9e]F[0xfe][0xf3][0x13][0xc9]?[0xcb][0xb6]+/P[0x96]M[0x1c]([0xb0]v[0xb8][0x99][0xff][0x0][0xd5]i[0xf9][0xc9][0x93][0xe8][0x84]z[0xb1][0xe0]{[0xf4][0xaa][0xd3][0xdd]j[0x8]|[0x8d][0x9][0xcd][0xdc] [0xe2]I[0xa4][0x19]XG}[0x87][0xf8][0xdb][0xd0][0xe]={U[0xed]0[0xd9].[0xf1][0xb]9[0xb9][0xf5][0xcd]9[0xfd][0xf3][0x9f][0xf6][0x8f][0xa0][0xe0]zS[\r][0x88][0xb4][0xc9][0x16]y[0xd6]mI[0x87][0xf6][0x92][0x8e]"n[0x12][0xc][0xf5][0x11][0x8e][0xff][0x0][0xef]u>[0xc3][0x8a][0xd2][0xbc]ke[0xb6][0x91][0xaf][0xc]b[0x4][0x19]s![0xc2][0xaf][0xbf][0xb5]T[0xd4][0xa4][0xb4][\n]"
10:18:29.897 [main] DEBUG org.apache.http.wire - http-outgoing-0 << "[0xb1]O[0x19][0x9a]g[0xff][0x0]U[0x14]c2[0xb7][0xfb][0xbe][0x83][0xdc][0xe0][0xe][0xf5][0x99][0x5][0x96][0xa1]o2[0xdd]jc[0xed][0x91]![0xcc]0)[0xdc]-[0x87]c[0xfe][0xdb][0xb5][0xdb][0xb6];[0x81][0xe6]4[[0xea]7Ro[0x8d]e[0x1a]?k9[0x18][0xac][0xb3][0xfb][0xfa][0xaa][0xb3][0xd4][0xf7][0xad][0xfb];[0xcb]y[0xd0]$[0x18]M[0x83][0x1e]V[0xdd][0xa5]1[0xdb][0x1e][0x9f]J[0x8e];[0xc8]&[0x89][0xa6]IT[0xa2][0x8c][0xb1]'[0x1b]G[0xbf][0xa5]d[0xde]E.[0xbb][0x8f][0xb2]3[0xd9][0xc5][0xff][0x0]?[0xea]1#[0x8f]H[0xc7][0xa7][0xfb]G[0xf0][0xf5][0xa6]+[0x97]5;[0x84][0xbd]v[0xb2][0xb5][0x85].n[0x93][0xef]HN[0x12][0xdf][0xd0][0xb3][0xe][0xff][0x0][0xec][0x8e]O[0xb7]Z[0xaf]a[0x14][0xba][0x1e][0xf7][0xbb]f[0xbe]i1[0xe6][0xdf][0x11][0xfb][0xc3][0xec]Ge[0x1d][0x80][0xe0]{[0x9a][Y[0xbf][0xb2]bKY[0xe0]X[0xe0]^[0x12]X[0x87][0xca]O[0xab]{[0x9f]^[0xf5]b[0xe3]RDe[0x8a][0x5][0xfb]M[0xc3][0xae]V([0xc8][0xe9][0xea][0xc7][0xa2][0xaf][0xb9][0xfc][0x1][0xe9]E[0x82][0xe5][0xd9]5;Xm[0xfe][0xd2][0xf3][0xa8][0x88][0xe0][0x2]9,O@[0x7]R}[0x87]5[0x8f]w[0xa5][0xcf][0xac][0xca][0xb7]S[0x8f][0xb1]"[0x1d][0xc9]m[0xc1]3zy[0xdd][0xb1][0xfe][0xc8][0xfc]s[0xd0]Go[0xa2]Omr[0xda][0x8a][0xcc][0x92]^7[0xfc][0xb3][0xdb][0x88]c[0x1f][0xdd]A[0xdb][0xdd][0xba][0x9f]j[0xd0][0x8f]S[0x84][0xab][0xb][0x83][0xf6]W[0x8c]e[0xd6]S[0x80][0x7][0xae]{[0xd0][0x4][0xf6][0xfa][0x9e]d[0x16][0xf7]k[0xe4]\v[0x1f][0xc2][0xff][0x0][0xee][0x9f][0xe9]P]_I|[0xd2]Y[0xe9][0xea][0x8f][0x82]Rk[0x99][0x6][0xe8][0xa2]=[0xc0][0x1f][0xc6][0xfe][0xc3][0x81][0xdc][0xf6][0xaa][0x97]1I[0xaf][0xc2]b`[0xf6][0xf6][\r][0xfc]x[0xdb]4[0xbf][0xee][0xff][0x0]q}[0xfa][0x9f]a[0xc9]t/&[0x8f][0x12]@P=[0x94]`*4k[0x83][0x18][0xf4]#[0xd2][0x81][0x8b]e[0xa7][0xb7][0x87]a1[0xda][0x17][0xb9][0xb7]c[0xbe]_1[0xb7]J[[0xbb][0x13][0xdf][0xfa]t[0x18][0xab]R[0xeb][0x16][0xeb][\n]"
10:18:29.897 [main] DEBUG org.apache.http.wire - http-outgoing-0 << "<e[0xa7][0x92]RDPF?x[0xe7][0xb8][0xc7]lw'[0x81]PM[0xaa][0xac][0x8d][0xe4][0xd8][0x85][0xb9][0x9c][0x80]O8H[0x87][0xab][0x9e][0xdf]N[0xa7][0xdb][0xad]T[0x8f]J[0xfb],[0xf2]_Ap[P[0x98]bYXa\[0xe][0x8a][0x17][0xf8]Tz~'[0x9e]h[0x11]'[0xf6];]]&[0xa5]}([0x17][0xe8][0x8][0x80][0xc5][0xf7]-[0x81][0xea][0x17][0xfb][0xc4][0xf7]c[0xd7][0xb6][0x5]X:[0x89][0xb1]R5[0x12][0xb1]"[0x8c][0xfd][0xa3]8L{[0xfa]UW[0xd7]"[0x83][0x9]z[0xa6][0x9][0xb3][0xb5]P|[0xde]i[0xec][0x13][0x1c][0x92]})[0xaf]lu<>[0xa9][0x18][0xf2][0x1][\r][0x1d][0x96]r[0xa0][0x8e][0x8d]![0x1f]y[0xbd][0x7]A[0xee]y[0xa7]`%u[0x97]Z[0x1f][0xbe]W[0x87]Ma[0xc4]G*[0xf7]#[0xd5][0xfb][0xaa][0x1f][0xee][0xf5]=[0xf0]8[0xa7][0xb5][0xb3]Z|[0xd6]$F?[0xe7][0x81][0xfb][0x87][0xe9][0xe9]P[0xb9][0xb8][0xb2]R`c<#[0x93][0x1b][0x9f][0x99]G[0xb1][0xac][0xf8]56[0xd7]c&[0xda]W[0x86][0xcf]8i[0x1][0xc4][0x92]{/[0xf7]W[0xfd][0xae][0xa7][0xb7][0xad][0x16][0x15][0xce][0x96][0x1d]Y[0xf5]e?[0xd8][0xdb]^,[0xed]k[0xd9][0x1][0xf2][0xd4][0xf7][\n]"
10:18:29.898 [main] DEBUG org.apache.http.wire - http-outgoing-0 << "[0xbd]\[0xfe]C[0xde][0x88]|<[0x96]2[0xc9]wa3%[0xe4][0xbf][0xeb][0xa4][0x93][0x9f];[0xd8][0xf6][0x3][0xd8][0xc][0xf]J[0xb2]t[0x81]n|[0xcd]8[0x8b]W[0x3][0xee]*[0xe2]6[0xf6][0xc7]j[0xab][0xff][0x0][0x9][0x16][0xdb][0xcf][0xec][0xc3]lN[0xa7][0x8c][0xf9][[0xb1][0x18][0x7][0xa1]g[0xe8][0x1][0xf4][0xe4][0x9e][0xc0][0xd6]z[0x96]Z[0x1a][0xd4][0x16][0xca]WT+b[0xeb][0xd5][0xa4]l#}[0xf][0xf4][0xa8][0xee]c[0xb8][0xd6][0xe3]1,F[0xd2][0xd1][0xba][0xcd]*~[0xf9][0xbd][0xd1]O[0xdc][0xfa][0xb7]>[0xd5]![0xd0][0xa3][0xbd]+.[0xac][0xc2][0xf6]e[0xe5][0x6]6[0xc7][0x9][0xff][0x0]a}}[0xce]M<[0xa5][0xe6][0x9d][0xf7]7^[[0xf][0xe1]?[0xeb][0x10]{z[0xff][0x0][0x9e][0x94]z[0x1]J[0xcb]O[0x9b][0xc3][0xd1][0x98][0xed][0x90][0xdd]Y[0xe7]sg[0x99][0x87][0xb9]=[[0xf1][0xfd]*[0xf3]j[0xd6][0xb]m[0xf6][0x83]p[0xa1]3[0xb4][0xc][0x1d][0xc5][0xbd][0x2][0x8e]I[0xf6][0x15][0x5][0xb6][0xb8][0xba][0xba][0xb0][0xd1][0x2]\[0xed];^[0xe5][0xce]"[0x88][0xfa]q[0xcb][0x11][0xe8]?1Q[0x1f][0xe]G[0x15][0xd1][0xd4]R[0xe1][0xce][0xa6]F[\r][0xcb][0x1][0x82]?[0xba][0x14]p[0xa3][0x8e][0xdf][0x8e]i[0xa0])[0xdf]i[0x97][0xda][0xb3][0xf9][0xf6][0xee][0xfa]:[0x8c][0x92]T[0xe2]i[0xbd][0x9b][0x1c] [0xfa]d[0x9a][0xb1]gu[0x15][0x82][0xad][0x94][0xd6][0xcb]b[0x87]h[0xfd][0xdb][0xfb][0xe7][0xd7][0xeb]S[0x8d]S[0xec][0xff][0x0][0xbb][0xd4][0x95]m[0x98][0xcb]Rv[0xde][0xf9][0xed]U[0xe7][0xb8][0x93]W[0x88][0xc5]e[\n]"
10:18:29.898 [main] DEBUG org.apache.http.wire - http-outgoing-0 << "[0x9b]v[0xeb]w:[0x9d][0x9f]T^[0xac]}[0xf8][0x1f]^[0x94][0xc0][0x9b]S[0x9a][0xce]8B][0x95]}[0xff][0x0]r07;[0x1f][0xf6]@[0xe4][0x9f][0xa7][0xf2][0xac]/'V[0x8d][0xc9][0x97][0xce]M3[0xb5][0xba]?[0xfa]@[0x1f][0xed]0[0xe8]?[0xd9][0x1f][0x89][0xab][0xb6][0x9a]T[0xba][0x9]g[0x80][0xbd][0xf2]?[0xdf]yNf[0x1e][0xc0][0xfa][0xb2]8[0xf6][0xab][0x83]Q[0xb4]xZ=Q[0x13][0xef][0x17]8+[0xf5][0xa6]H[0xdd]=[0xac][0xbe][0xce][0x16][0xc8]"F[0xbc][0x94]Q[0x82][0xf][0xb8][0xf5][0xf7][0xaa][0xba][0x8a]Z[0xda]0[0x9d]'[0xfb]5[0xc3][0x1f][0x94] [0xc9][0x94][0xfa]m[0x1c][0x9f][0xc3][0xeb]T[0xaf]c[0x9b]Rq.[0x9a][\r][0x89][0xeb][0xf6][0xb7]\[0x17][0x1f][0xec][0xa7][0xf7][0x8e]>[0x87][0xb1]k2[0xe9][0xdb][0xbe][0xd1][0x3][0x1b][0xbd][0xbc][0xcc][q[0x9b][0xfe][0x4]z}8[0x14][0x5][0xc6]&[0xa5]yw[0xba]=Q[0xff][0x0][0xb1][0xd4][0xc][0xed][0xc][0x3]8[0xf5]/[0xd1]~[0x83][0xf3][0x15][0x93]y[0xae]iS#[0xe9][0xba][0x6][0x9e]uk[0xc1][0xff][0x0]<[0x6][0x12]3[0xfd][0xe7][0x90][0xff][0x0][0x93]F[0xab][0xe1][0x9b][0x9f][0x10][0xb0][0xbc][0xf1][0xe][0xa4][0xb6]v[0xb1][0x9c][0xa5][0xa5][0xb9][0x1b]c[0x1f][0xed]9[0xe0][0x93][0xec]>[0x95]5[0xac][0x17][0x1a]T"-[0x1e][0x3][0x16][0x95][0xd5][0xa6][0x92]1[0xe6][0x9f][0xf6][0x95]z[0x9f][0xab]q[0xed][0xde][0x8d]@[0xe4]5[0xaf][0x8]j[0x92][0xb2]_[0xf8][0x83]RR[0xd2]|[0xab][0x1c][0x0][0xca][0xeb][0xe8][0xaa][0xf]_[0xc3]=:[0xd7]=[0xaa]x;R[0xd3][0xa0][[0xb1][0x11][0x96][0xd9][0xf9]V^X[0xf]p:[0x1f]n[0xa2][0xbd][0xaa][0xca]+U[0x6][0xe2][0xc][0xcb]#[0x8c]4[0xce]wH}[0x89]=>[0x94][0xcb][0x9b]H[0xed][0xa2][0x92][0xe6]'[0x8a][0x4]#[0xf7][0x91][0xcd][0xfe][0xa9][0xfe][0xa3][0xd7][0xfc][0x8a][0x97][0x1]\[0xf9][0xeb][0x4]S[0x83][0x15][0xaf]I[0xd5][0xfc]#m[0xe2]6[0x92][0xe7]J[0xb5]k[0x9][0xd4]nh[0xe6][0xe0][0xca]q[0xfc][0xb][0xd4][0x8f]s[0x83][0xec]k[0xce][0xae]m[0xa5][0xb4][0x9d][0xe0][0x9d][\n]"
10:18:29.898 [main] DEBUG org.apache.http.wire - http-outgoing-0 << "H[0x87][0x4]VMXm[0x16],u[[0x9d]:t[0xb8][0xb6].T[0xfb][0xae]:[0x8a][0xe9][0xb4]o[0x88][0x9a][0x9d][0x8e][0xa0].nH[0x9c]7[0xe][0xcc]2[0xfb]}[0x8d]q[0x95][0xb7][0xe1]=[0x19][0xb5][0xbd]j[0xb]\e3[0xb9][0xc9][0x19][0xc0][0x14]!\[0xf7][0x89]u=6[0xff][0x0]N[0xb7][0x92]h[0xcc][0xe6][0xe9]7En[0x8b][0xba]V[0xf5][0xda]==[0xce][0x7][0xad]f[0xc5][0xa3][0xea](wN[0x4][0x96][0x0][0xe5]4[0xc5][0x93];G[0xfb]L>[0xf1][0xff][0x0]d|[0xa3][0xd0][0xd5][0xbb][0x1d][0x1e]M[0x5][0x19][0xb4][0xf0]n[0x15][0xf1][0xe6]$[0xcd][0x99][0xe]=[0x1c][0xf3][0xf4][0x1d]=[0xaa][0xd7][0xf6][0xe5][0x9f][0xcb][0x1f][0xef][0x1a][0xe9][0xb8][E\[0xca][0xc7][0xbe][0x7][0xa7][0xbf]A[[0x14]Om}k$D#,B%[0xe6]6[0x1]v[0x1][0xed][0xd8]V}[0xd9]:[0xca][0x11][0xa7][0xc2][0xf][0x18][0x17][0xf2][0x2][0x11]}[0xd0]u[0x93][0xf9]{[0xd2][0xdc][0xe8]'Y[0x91].5m[0xab][0xb0][0xee][0x8a][0xde][0x13][0x95]C[0xd8][0xb9][0xff][0x0][0x96][0x84]z}[0xd1][0xdb][0xd6][0xa7][0x92][0xfa]}1[0x19][0xaf][0xf0][0xf6][0xe8]2nW[0xf8]G[0xab][0xe][0xdf]Z[0x0][0xa9]e[0x4][0xba][0x12][0xb7][0x9f][0xbe][0xf1]\[0xe6]K[0xd3][0xcc][0xad][0xfe][0xff][0x0][0xb7][0xb0][0xe0]U[0xe9][0xb5][X[0xd2]2[0x8e]f[0x92]_[0xf5]qB7;[0xfd][0x7]a[0xee]p[0x5]A[0x16][0xa5]6[0xab][0x10]}1T[[0xbf]K[0xc9]G[0xca][0xc3][0xd5][0x13][0xab]}N[0x7][0xd7][0xa5]C[0x6][0x84][0xba]{[0xcb]sc+[0xb][0xb9][0x8e]f[0x92]^|[0xef]c[0xe8][0x7]`8[0x14][0xc4]C>[0x87]&[0xa5]p[0xb7][0x97]L[0x96][0xee][0x87]tv[0xb1][0xfc][0xc9][0x9f]Y[0xf][0xf1][0x9f][0xd0]{[0xd5][0xc4][0xd4][0x1a]7[0x11]^[0xa7][0x93]![0xe8][0xe3][0xee]7[0xbe]{T2k[0xb0][0xdb][0xc8][0x96][0xd7][0x88][0xd1]^I[0xc4]p([0xdc]f?[0xec]z[0xff][0x0]![0xeb]Iq[0xa7]I[0xab][0xc6]c[0xd4][0x80][V?[0xf1][0xe8][0x87];[0xbf][0xdf]a[0xd7][0xe8]8[0xfa][0xd0][0x1e][0xa0][0xf7][0x92]j [0xc7]`[0x17][0xc9]<5[0xdc][0x8b][0xb9][0xf][0xa8]E[0xfe]?[0xaf][0xdd][0xfa][0xd4][0x16][0x9a]ch[0x8a][0xc3]O[0xdd],n[0xdb][0xa5][0x8e]V[0xcb][0xc8][0xdd][0xdb]w[0xaf][0xf9][0x3][0xb5]N#[0x9f]M[0x0]D[0xa6][0xe2][0xd9]F<[0xbf][0xe3]A[0xed][0xea]=[0xaa]([0xf5]Q[0xa9][0xa9][0x1a]K$[0xa0][0x1d][0xaf]p[0xff][0x0][0xea][0xe3]=[0xc7][0xfb]M[0xec]8[0xf5]4[0xc4]Z[0x1a][0xd5][0xae][0xc5][0xb][0xbd][0xe7]bB[0xdb]([0xcc][0x84][0xfd]==[0xfa][0xe][0xf5]R[0xef]K[0x1a][0xa3]$[0xfa][0x99][0x1b][0xe2];[0xa0][0x86]3[0x95][0x84][0xf6]$[0xff][0x0][0x1b]~[0x83][0xb0][0xef]J[0xba],qH[0xf7]Q[0xcc][0xe6][0xf9][0xfe][0xfd][0xd3][0x9c][0xb3][0xfb][0x1e][0xc1]}[0x87][0x15]Z[0xeb]W[[0x1c]&[0xa1][0xfb][0xa7]c[0xb6]2[0xa3]"S[0xe8][0xa3][0xd7][0xda][0x9a]Ar[0xd2]jSY[0x9d][0x97][0xc7]rv[0xb8][0x1d][0xf][0xfb][0xde][0x95][0x1b][0xea][0x13]jK[0x8b][0x17][0xf2][0xad][0x8f][[0xb2]2_[0xfe][0xb9][0x83][0xd7][0xfd][0xe3][0xc7][0xa6]j[0x9b][0xdb]K[0xa9][0xa9][0x17][0xe9][0xb2][0xd8][0xff][0x0][0xcb][0xa6]~[0xf7][0xfd]t#[0xaf][0xfb][0xa3][0x8f]Ri[0xde]T[0xf6]<[0xdb][0xfe][0xfa][0x1][0xff][0x0],I[0xf9][0x97][0xfd][0xda]v[0x15][0xc9]-[0xf4][0xe1][0xa5][0xa6]4[0xc0][0x11]3[0xb9][0xe2]s[0x90][0xe4][0xf5]$[0xfa][0x9f]ZV[0xd6][0x91][0x9b][0xec][0xf1]D[0xcf]zF~[0xcc]N[0xd2][0xa3][0xfb][0xcc]{/[0xbf]~[0xc2][0xaa]&[0xb0]uE+[0xa6]0[0x8][0xa7]l[0x97][0xc]2[0x10][0xf7][\n]"
10:18:29.898 [main] DEBUG org.apache.http.wire - http-outgoing-0 << "?[0x89][0xbf]A[0xef][0xd2][0x93][0xfb]:[0x8][0xc1]h[0xcb][0xac][0xec]w4[0xfb][0xb3]#[0x1f]V=[0xff][0x0][0xa7]lQ`[0xb9]a[0xb4][0xf8][0xe5]q5[0xf3][0x8b][0x8b][0x9c][0x10][0xae][0x6][0xd5][0x88][0x1e][0xa1][0x7]ory=[0xfd])[0xb3][0xdf][0xbe][0x95][0xb][0xcb]s'[0x99]j[0x83]&C[0xf7][0x90]{[0xfa][0xd5];[0xad]U[0xf4][0xf6]Hn[0x97][0xcd][0x92]^"1[0xf5][0xa8][0xec]=I[0xe2][0x91]!2[0xba][0xcf]t[0xcb]+[0xa9][0xcc]j[0xbf]r?q[0xea][0xda]?[0x86])[0xd8]W[0xee]XG}]D[0x93][0xe5],[0xcf]+o[0x9e]d[0xff][0x0][0xae][0x9e][0x83][0xfd][0x8f][0xcf][0xd2][0xac]Mk[0x1c][0x8c][0x1e]2a[0x94][0xe][0x19]8[0xfc][0xc5]e[0xcd][0x10][0xb7][0xdd]42[0x8b]}[0xa3]-[0x9f][0xb9][0xf8][0xfa]T[0x16][0xfa][0x84][0x9a][0x99][0xd9]8kX[0xe7][0x9f]*[0xd3][0x8f]\[0xf5][0xb][0xed][0xd4][0xd1]`;kMf[0xeb]Y[0x93][0xec][0xec][0x1b]K[0x8b][0xb4][0xcc]0[0xf7][0x3][0xd6]<[0x8f][0x95][0xda]9'[0xb5]l[\r][0x1e][0xc5]m[0xbe][0xca]-[0x94]G[0x92]s[0xce][0xec][0x9e][0xac][[0xa9]>[0xe6][0xac][0xdc][0xda][0xc3]v[0x9e]\[0xf1][0x87][0x1d][0xb3][0xd4]}[\r]s[0x93][0xea]:[0x85][0xac][0xad]o[0xa5][0xa7][0xda][0xc6]v[0xcd]r[0xe3]r[0xdb]{[0xf][0xf9][0xe8]G[0xa0]8[0x1d][0xc8][0xe9]X[0x1a][0x96]oo[0xe6][0xf0][0xe4]hdw[0xbd][0x81][0xce][0xd8][0xe1]Q[0xba]r}[0x14][0x17][0xf9][0xe9]R[0xdb]+[0xeb][0xb1][0x9][0xae][0xa5][0x9]lG[0xfc]y[0xc2][0xfc][0xff][0x0][0xdb]V[0x1c][0x9f][0xa0][0xc0][0xfa][0xd4][0xfa]][0xbd][0x99]V[0xb9][0x86]Ss;[0x8c]Iq)[0xcc][0x87][0xd8][0xff][0x0]t{[0xc][\n]"
10:18:29.898 [main] DEBUG org.apache.http.wire - http-outgoing-0 << "/la[0x8c]=[0xe2]N[0xb6]N[0x83]-6p[0xbf][0xf0].[0xdf][0xe7][0xbd][0x0][0x12][0xe9]1[0x6][0x13]Y[0x1f][0xb2]L[0xa3][0x0][0xc6]0[0xa7][0xd8][0x8a][0xa3]q[0xe2][0x1f][0xb1]]&[0x9f]y[0x1]k[0xf9][0x6]cH[0x88][0xda][0xe3][0xfb][0xc4][0x9e][0x10]{[0x9f][0xc0]v[0xa8]m[0xf5][0x9b][0xdb][0xf9][0x8d][0xb4][0xc0][0xe9][0xb0][\r][0xdb]![\r]p=c[0x7][0xee][0xf]v[0xe7][0xd0][0xe][0xb5][0xb3][0x1e][0x97]e[0x14][\r][0x2][[0xa9]G;[0x9c][0xb7][0xcc][0xce][0xbc]X[0xf2]O[0xbd][0x0]g[0xcd][0xa3][\r]Q[0x7][0xf6][0xc9]K[0x84][0xce]E[0xaa]q[\n]"
10:18:29.898 [main] DEBUG org.apache.http.wire - http-outgoing-0 << "[0x9e][0xc4][0xf7]r=O[0x1e][0x83][0xbd]![0x82][0xf3]M[0xff][0x0]PM[0xdd][0xb0][0xff][0x0][0x96]L~u[0x1e][0xc7][0xbf][0xf9][0xe2][0x9b]4[0x9e][0x1f][0x87][0xcf][0xf3]L[0xd6][0xa0][0xe0]B[0xdc][0xc8]O[0xa2][0x1][0xcb][0x1f]a[0xf9]TV[0xf2][0xdc]k[0xd1]y[0x86]F[0xb3][0xb5]=`F[0xfd][0xfb]{9[0x1f]p{/>[0xe3][0x91]T![0xa3]^[0x86][0xf5][0x9e]-5[\r][0xdd][0xc2]q"[0xe7]j[0xc2][0xdb]n[0xc7][0xd8]d[0xfd]:[0xd5][0x9][0xf4][0x3]=[0xca][0xea][0x13][0xcf][0xbe][0xfd]9FU[0xc4]I[0xf4]_[0xfd][0x98][0xe4][0xd6][0x9c][0x9a]%[0xbc]J[\r][0x92][0x8b]9[0x10]|[0xa6]![0x80]~[0xa3][0xbf][0xd7][0xf3][0xcd]R[0x9f][M>h[0xed]5[0x4]"[0xea]Q[0xfb][0x94][0x88]g[0xce][0xfa]z{[0x93][0xc0][0xa6][0x84]0[0xdf][0xb4][0xe]"[0xbe][0x8f][0xc9][0x90][0xf4][0x90]r[0x8f][0xf8][0xf6][0xa8][0xa7][0xbe][[0xad][0xd0]Z[0xc2][0xb7]D[0x1c]31[0xc4]H}[0xdb][0xb9][0xf6]^~[0x95]5[0xde][0x9b]6[0xa5][0x19]]Gj@[0xe5][0xd6]&[0xce][0xdf]~[0xff][0x0]A[0x81][0xf5][0xaa]k[0xc][0xba]J[0x4][0x8d]L[0xb6]H0[0x10][0xf][0x9a]![0xed][0xed][0xfe]x[0xaa][0x17][0xa1]R;)[0xb4][0xd9]E[0xc5][0xc3][0xb6][0xa3][0x18][0xe4][0x6][0x1f][0xea]?[0xdc]^[0x98][0xf7][0xeb][p[0xdd]Gq[0x18][0x96])7[0xa9][0xe7]=[0xc7][0xd6][0xa8][0xc9][0xa9][0xdb])Q[0x11]7[0x12][0xb7][0xdd][0x8a].[[0xf1][0xfe][0xe8][0xf7]8[0xaa][0x12][0xe9]3[0xdc]K[0xf6][0xb6]t[0x8d][0xbb][0xd9][0xa1][0xfd][0xd3][0x8f][0xf6][0xcf][0xf1][0x1f][0xc8]:[0x4]O9[0x96]iK[0xe8]J[0x1e]`q#[0xb7][0x16][0xfe][0xe3]?[0xc4]}[0x87][0xe2]E\[0xd3][0xc5][0xbc][0xb2][0x87][0xbc]-%[0xfc][0xc3]8[0xc0]C[0xdf]b[0xf4][0x3][0xf5][0xf7][0xa7][0xd9]j[0x11]J[0xbe]Q_"H[0xc6][0xc]G[0x8d][0xa3][0xdb][0xda][0xb0][0xb5][0xbf][0x11][0xd8]<Lc[0x1e]a[0x8c][0xfc][0xb3][0x3][0x82][0x8][0xeb][0x83][0xde][0xa2]RQ[0xdc][0xa4][0xae]t:[0xa9][0xb6]xL[0x93]g[0xcc]A[0x95]u?0[0xfc]k[0xc4][0xbc]_;\[0xea][0xef]+[0xfd][0xe2]:[0xe3][0x4][0xfd]k[0xa4][0xd4]|e-[0xc2][0xa9]yp[0x87][0xa2][0xaf];G[0xa9][0xf5]5[0xc2][0xdf][0xdd]}[0xae][0xe9][0xe5][0xc6][0x1]<V[0x1c][0xee]Ob[0xda]I[0x10][0x3][0xcd]z[0x9f][0xc3]]9[0xec]4[0xd9][0xb5][0xb2]b[0x0][0x9c][0x1f]7[0xe5][0x1b]G[0xfb]U[0xe5]Y[0xed]^[0xcb][0xf0][0xc2][0xea][0xc2][0xfb]OH&[0x2]K[0x8b]c[0xf2]$[0x87]*[0xbe][0xea][0xbd]3[0xef][0xd6][0xaa];[0x99][0x9d]][0x96][0xaf]6[0xba][0x84]Y)[0xb2][0x8c]}[0xe9]'_[0xde][0x9f][0xf7]S[0xb0][0xff][0x0]i[0xbf]/[#@[0xb2]B[0xd2][0xa0]qt[0xd8][0xdd]v[2[0xb6]:e[0xbb][0x8f]n[0x83][0xb6]*{[0xdb][0x1b]yA[0xb8][0x91][0xfc][0x87][0x8c]n[0xfb]@m[0xa5]~[0xa7][0xd3][0xeb]X[0xf1][0xeb]w[0xd3]H-[0xc0][0x11][[0x13][0x85][0xd4][0xde]3[0xb5][0xff][0x0][0xdc]S[0xd4][0xff][0x0][0xb4]x[0xf6]5[0xa8][0xcb]7z[0xe1][0xd0][0xfc][0xb8][0xb5][0x10]f2[0x9d][0xb0]4[0x3]/![0xf4][0xdb][0xfd]x[0x15]*XI[0xa9][0xed][0x9f]Rdxs[0xba];8[0xdb]tC[0xd0][0xb9][0xff][0x0][0x96][0x87][0xff][0x0][0x1d][0x1e][0x9d][0xea][0xcd][0xbd][0x85][0xb4][0x1][0x99]W[0xcd]yF$[0x9a]S[0xbd][0xe4][0x1e][0xe4][0xf6][0xf6][0x1c]U[0xb][0xf6][0xfe][0xc4][0x2][6,\[0xfc][0xb6] ni[0x8f][0xa2][0xe][0xb9][0xf7][0xe8];[0x9a][0x0][0xb3]>[0x9e][0xd6][0xa5][0xee]l[0xa4]Xp7<nv[0xc0]z[0xfa][0x9e][0x95]B[0xd3]Y[0x9b]Yc[0x1d][0xa2][0xb]0?[0xe5][0xac][0xeb][0x96][0x93][0xde]5[0xe3]#[0xd1][0x8f]^[0xc2][0xa4][0xb3]c[0xad][0x1d][0xfa][0x88][0x9][0xb0][0xe7][0xfb];[0xf8]P[0x8e][0xef][0xfd][0xf3][0xff][0x0][0x8e][0x8f]C[0xd6][0xb4]/`[0xb7][0xb9][0x8c][0x99][0xf0][0xa1][0x6]D[0x99][0xc1]O|[0xd3][0x2][0x98][0xd1][0xad][0x17]{H[0xad]4[0xce]0[0xd3][0xca][0xd9][0x90][0xfe]=[0x87][0xb0][0xc0][0xf6][0xaa][0xd7]Z[0x9f][0xf6][0x2]![0xbb]v[0xb9][0x81][0xce][0xd8][0xf6][0xc][0xcc]O`[0x17][0xf8][0xbf][0xcf]"[0xa9][0x8d]V[0xfa]I6+[0x11][0xa7][0xe7][0x9][0xa9]2d[0xc9][0xfe][0xea][0x9e][0xdf][0xed][0x1c][0x83][0xd8][0x1e][0xb5][0xa3]om[0x4][0x4][0xc8][0x9f][0xbc]w[0x1c][0xcc][0xed][0xbd][0x98][0xbc]{{t[0xa6]+[0x80][0x86]mM[0x4][0xb7]2[0x8]m[0x9c]em[0xe1]|[0x96][0x1f][0xed][0xb8][0xff][0x0][0xd0]W[0x1e][0xe4][0xd4]R[0xd8][0x8][0x8]m<-[0xbb]([0xc0][0x8d]F[0x11][0x87][0xa6]*[0xad][0xfc][0xe3]I[0xcc][0xd6][0xf2][0x5]-[0xff][0x0].[0xdd]|[0xd3][0xe8][0xaa]9[0xcf][0xf9][0xe0]T[0x16][0xf7][0xd2][0xea][0xea]|[0xf2][0xd6][0x91][0xf4]kU8[0x93][0xfe][0x6][0xc3][0xa7][0xd1][0x13][0xda][0x9d][0x80][0x99]5[0xe3]q4[0x96]V[0xd1][0x6][0xbc][0x8b][0x89]C[0x9f][0xdd][0xc4]}[0xc8][0xeb][0xfe][0xe8][0xe7][0xe9]H[0xda]tr[0x93]%[0xd1]73[0x91][0x8f]1[0xc6]6[0xfb] [0x1c]([0xfa]s[0xea]MY[0xfb]%[0xb4][0x91]$K[0x12][0xc4][0xa9][0xf7]<[0xb1][0xb7]o[0xd2][0xb3].u9,[0xee][0x5][0xa6][0xd1]t[0xe7][0x8f]9N[0x16]/[0xfa][0xe8]{}[0x6]I[0xa6]/A..[G[0x88][0xcb]p[0xfb][0xed][0x17][0xf8][0xcf][0xde]OA[0xef]H[0xc][0xba][0xa2][0x7][0x94][0x98]m[0x18]q[\n]"
10:18:29.898 [main] DEBUG org.apache.http.wire - http-outgoing-0 << "[0x9c]<[0x83][0xfd][0xb2]:[0xf][0xf6]G>[0xa7][0xb5]Z[0x8e][0xcd]K-[0xc5][0xc4][0x82][0xe6]\eX[0x8f][0x91]?[0xdc]^[0xdf]^O[0xbd]T[0x9e]$[0xb3]W[0xb8][0x8a]e[0xb7][0x3][0xef][0x6][0xfb][0x8d][0xed][0x8f]_[0xa5]1z[0x12]=[0x9a][\r][0xad]m[0x8b]y[0x14]av[0xc][0xc]zb[0xa9][0x8d]^Yn[0x1a][0xc9][0x4]i2[0x1c]=[0xc3]s[0x12][0xfb][0xf][0xef]7[0xb7]A[0xdf][0xd2][0xa2][0x86][0xf6]]L[0x94][0x99]^[0xc9]?[0xe7][0x89][0xf9]d[0x93][0xdf]?[0xc2]=[0xba][0xfa][0xe3][0xa5]Xu[0x8b][0xca][0x10][0xf9]j#_[0xba][0x80]`[0xf][0xa5];\D[0xa9]m[0xc][0xb]!9[0x96]G[0xff][0x0]Y$[0x9c][0xb3][0xfd]}[0xbd][0x87][0x2][0xb3]n'6[0x3]t[0x4][0xb6][0xe3][0xf2][0xdb][0xf5].[0xd9][0xaa][0xb3]_\B[0xe6][0x1b]?[0xf4][0x88][0xc7][0xe][[0x91][0x17][0xe3][0xdc][0xfb]*t[0xc][0x84][0xb4][0x8a][0xc6]Gn[0x19][0xdb][0xef][0x1f]oa[0xec]8[0xaa][0xb5][0xc4]Ko2[0xde][0xb8][0x9a][0xe8][0x86]u9[[0xe1][0x88][0xfa][0x9f][0xef]7[0xbf]n[0xd5]b[0xe0]$[0xca]L[0xb8][0xc0][0xe7]$[0xe3][0x1e][0xf9][0xaa]7-[0x0][0x0][0xb9]a![0xe1]6[0xc][0xb9]>[0xc3][0xbd]W[\r]q[0xc7][0xf6][0x88][0xf9]s[0xf2]*[0xf2][0xa3][0xfd][0xef]S[0xfa]:~@zG[0xd9][0xb5]i[0xe][0xe9][0x92][0xe3][0xfb][0x17][0xb5][0xab][0x1d][0xb7],=_[0x1c][0xaa][0xff][0x0][0xb0]9[0xf5][0xc7]J[0xe8][0xac][0xe6][0xb6][0x96][0xdd][0x5][0xa6][0xc1][0x12][0x0][0xaa][0x88]6[0xec][0xf6][0xc7]j[0xb1]mu[0x5][0xdc]~d2[0x6]P2{[0x15][0xfa][0xfa]V[\r][0xf5][0xbc][0xfa][0xcc][0xa5][0xf4])~[0xc5][0x83][0xf3][0xea] |[0xaf][0xea][0xa8][0xbf][0xc5][0xee][0xdd][0x7][0xb9][0xae]3quU[0x86]+[0x8c]X[0x7]:[0xab][\r][0xcb][0x14][0x18][0xe4]z[0xc9][0xd9]W[0xdc][0xfe]G[0x81]P[0xd8][0xac][0x8d]:[0x1f][0x11]mk[0xd5]9[0x8d][0xe5][0xd9]=[0xd0]w?[0xed][0x1e]~[0x95]{M[0x92][\r];[0xfd][0xe]x>[0xc9]3[0x1d][0xcd]#[0x1c][0x89][0x8f][0xf7][0x8b][0x9e]I>[0xa4][0xff][0x0][0x85]_[0xd4]f[0xb2][0x82][0xd8][0x9b][0xd2][0xa2]68U#%[0x9b][0xb0]P9'[0xe9][0xcd][0x3][0x1d]4[0x11][0xdc][0xc6]c[0x95][0x4][0x8a][0xdd][0x88][0xcd]ss[0xdd][0xdf]YJ[0xd0]hK[0xfd][0xa1][0x12][0x1c]J\[0x13][0x1d][0xb7][0xd1][0x87][0xdf]?[0xec][0x8f][0xc7][0x1d]hkM[[0x99]2L[0xba]7[0xfc][0xf8][0x87][0xfd][0xfe]=\[0x8e][0x8b][0xfe][0xc8]?Z[0xe8]lf[0xb5][0x96][0xd9][0x5][0xa6][0xc5][0x89][0x6][0x2] [0xc6][0xcf]lv[0xa0]E[0x1d]2[0xd6][0xd2]_[0xf4][0xc1]3][0xdd][0x11][0x86][0x9e]_[0xbe][0x99][0xec][0x17][0xa2][0xf]a[0xf9][0x9a]/[0xb4][0xd8][0x89]k[0xa8][0xe4][0xfb],[0xc8][0x9]3[0x3][0x81][0xff][0x0][0x2][0xf6][0xa8][0xf5][0x8f]"[0xde]P[0xd6][0xa5][0xff][0x0][0xb4][0xd8][0x13][0x14]0[0xc][0xb4][0x9f][0xef][0xe][0x81]}X[0xf1][0xf5][0xe9]T[0xec][0xd6]}Ba[0x1e][0xbf][0xb5]n[0x94][0xe5]l[0xd7][0xfe]=[0xc7][0xa1][0xff][0x0][0xa6][0x87][0xdc][0xf1][0xe8]([0x2][0x94]:[0xed][0xde][0xa1]7[0xd9][0x11]R[0xd4][\r][0xf3][0xa1])0[0xf5][0x89]O_[0xa9][0xe2][0xb4]SH[0xb4]H[0xa4]F[0x8c][0xca][0xd2][0xf3]$[0xb2][0x9d][0xd2]9[0xf5]-[0xfe][0x1c][0xe][0xc2][0xaf]^YGy[0x19][0x8e]d[0xdc][0xa7][0xa7][0xa8][0xfa]V[\r][0xc6][0xa9]>[0x95]q[0xf6][0x4]C[0xce]<[0xdc][0xe1]m[0xfd]<[0xd6][0xe7][0x1f]A[0x96]5B[0x12][0xf2]i48[0x9a]K[0x99][0x4][0x96][0xb][0xc7][0x9a][0xc7][0xe6][0x8b][0xd0][0x1f]QT[0xcd][0xe4][0xfa][0x84]bKbm[0xad][0x9b][0x95][0x95][0x97][0xf7][0x8e]?[0xd9]S[0xf7]~[0xad][0xcf][0xb0][0xef][0xb9][0x16][0x90][0xb3]2[0xdc][0xdd][0xcc]/%[0xc6]Q[0xb1][0xfb][0xb4][0xcf][0xf7][0x17][0xa0][0xfa][0x9c][0x9f]~[0xc2][0xa4][0xfa],[0x96][0xce][0xd2][0xd8][0x8c][0x83][0xcb]@z7[0xd3][0xdf][0xfc][0xfb]U[0xa6]&[0xbb][0x1c][0xfc]ZY[0xb1]v[0x93]M][0xa5][0x8e]dG9[0xf3]O[0xa9]'[0xbf][0xf9][0xe2][0xa7]]N[0x5]S[0xe7]1[0x86]@pb`K[0x13][0xe8][0x7]S[0xf8]U[0xfb];[0xe4][0xd4][0xc3][0xc5][0xa4][0xa2][0xc8][0xf1][0x9d][0xb3]K/[0x11][0xc4]}8[0xe5][0xcf][0xd3][0x8f]R*[0x9e][0xb7]e[0xa6]i[0x8]/[0xef][0xee][0xcf][0xdb][0xc2][0x9f].[0xe9][0xf0][0x8][0xc0][0xfb][0xaa][0x7][\n]"
10:18:29.898 [main] DEBUG org.apache.http.wire - http-outgoing-0 << "[0xbe][0xc3][0xf1]'[0xbb][0xb8][0xb9]L[0xdd]p[0xbc][0xb6][0x12]]][0xff][0x0][0xa0][0xc1][0x10][0xc8][0x1c]y[0xaf][0xe8][0x9][0xe8][0xa0][0xfa]r~[0x9d]+[0xcb]/[0xb5]C4[0xac][0xcd][0xca]tT'[0x85][0x1e][0xd5]{[0xc5]>/[0xb8][0xd7][0xde]4`[0xb1][0xc5][0x8][0xc2][0xaa][0x8c][0x6]=[0xd8][0xd7]0[0xce]X[0xe4][0x9a][0xe6][0x9d][0xa4][0xcb]N[0xc8][0x9a]y[0xcc][0x8d][0x91][0xc0][0xf4][0x15][0x6]i[0xa4][0xd1]RM[0xc7]f[0xb5][0xfc]=[0xab][0xcd][0xa4][0xea]1O[0x13][0x95][0xf9][0x80]>[0xf5][0x8e])[0xca][0xc5]H"[0x98][0x8f][0xa2]t[0x9b][0x85][0xd4][0x4]SkO[0xe6][0xbb][0x10][0xd0][0x3][0xc5][0xba][0xfa]`t-[0xee]J[0xe8][0xe6]H[0xdd][0x18]J[0x14][0xa6]>`[0xdd]1^c[0xe0]/[0x13][0xb][0xab][0xf][0xec][0xdb][0xa8][0x9e][0xe9][0x82][0xfe][0xee]4[0x19]f[0xf6][0x1e][0x9f]\[0xf1]]B[0xd9]_[0xdb][0xbf][0x99][0xa9][0xb7][0xda]l3[0x94][0xb3][0x8c][0xe5]`[0xe7][0x82][0xc7][0xfe]Z[0xe8]#[0xb5]j[0xb5]CB[0xc9]=[0xf2]1[0x1a][\n]"
10:18:29.898 [main] DEBUG org.apache.http.wire - http-outgoing-0 << "[0x99][0xad]2|[0xc9][0xa5][0x19]D[0xf5][0xf2][0x87]W=[0xd9][0xf5]&[0xb5][0xb4][0xb8][0xac][0xf6]5[0xc4][0xe][0xd3]L[0xe3][0x12][0xcd])[0xcc][0xa7][0xd8][0xfa][0xf]a[0xc5]X[0x8a]x[0xe6][0x8c]<L[0x19]1[0xc1][0x1d][0xbd][0xbd][0xab][0x12][0xf1][0xde][0xfa]f}[0xf]h[0xb9]S[0x87][0xbb]o[0xf5][0x3][0xd4][0x1f][0xef][0x9f]a[0xc7][0xa9][0xaa][0x19]{W[T[0xb]+[0xb3][0xa5][0xce]q[0xf][0x92]3#[0x9f]@[0xa3][0xef]OQYP[0x1b][0xab][0x99]U<@[0xa2]1[0xc1][0x86][0xdd]Nboy[0xf]Foo[0xba]=[0xfa][0xd5][0xed]-[0xa3][0x8a]FK[0x80][0xdf][0xda][0x4]bYe[0xe5][0xa4][0xff][0x0]t[0xf4][0xb][0xfe][0xc8][0xe3][0xeb]V5[0x1b][0x9b]H[0xe1][0x9]t7[0xf9][0x87][0x9][0x12][0xae][0xe7][0x90][0xfa]([0x1c][0x93][0xfe]M1[0xb]8[0xc][0xac][0x1c][0x2][0xb8][0xf9][0xb7]t[0xc7][0xbd]r[0xd2][0xbd][0xef][0x98][I[0xdd][0xf6][0x1c][0xe6]I[0x8][0xc9]>[0xbe]P=[0xde][0xe9][0xe9][0x9e][0xd7][0x16][0xda][0xf6]&[0xdd][0xa9][0x82][0xfa]vs[0x1d][0xb0]m[0xc6]?O4[0x8f][0xbd][0xf4][0x1f]([0xf7]5[0xb4][0x1a]9b[0x12]!R[0x98][0xea]:[0x1]LF[0x15][0xa9][0xb7]E2[0xdb][0x82][0xf2]7[0xdf][0x91][0xce][0xe9][0xf][0xd4][0x9f][0xff][0x0]W[0xa5]U[0xbe]h[0x15][0x96]I$0[0xcc]~[0xe1]@K[0xb7][0xb0][0x3][0x93]Rj[0x11]I[0xa9][0xb7][0x99][0xa5]7[0x91][0x83][0xf3]^[0xe3][0xe5]P[0x8b][0xfc]_[0xef][0x1e]>[0xb5]V[0x12][0xb6][0xcc][0xd1]<~T[0xc7][0xab][0xb3]n2{[0xee]=j[0xd1];[0x4]Wws[0xb7][0x97][0xa8][0xb3]Y[0xa1][0xfb][0xa8][0x87][0x6]A[0xfe][0xd3][0xe][0x9f]A[0xf9][0xd6][0x92]<q[0xc6] [0x8e]4X[0xff][0x0][0xb8][0xab][0xc5]f\][0xc4][0x83][0xcb][0x97][0xe7]c[0xd2] 2[0xc7][0xe8]?[0xad]g[0x91]t[0x1f]%[0x99]m;[0xdb]+[0xfc][0xe7][0xea][0xde][0x9e][0xc3][0xf1][0xa7]a[0x17][0xe7][0xb9][0x9a][0xd6]FM0}[0xa2]@~h[0x9][0xfd][0xda]{[0x96][0xed][0xf4][0xeb]R[0xda]<s[0xc8][0xb2][0xcc][0xe6]k[0x95][0xec][0xe3][0x1e]_[0xae][0xd5][0xed][0xf5][0xeb]Iks[0x1][0x89]V[0x1c]*[0xf][0xe0][0x3][0x1b][\n]"
10:18:29.898 [main] DEBUG org.apache.http.wire - http-outgoing-0 << "[0xab]y<S[0x92][0xb6][0xe8]d[0x99]x[0xf3][0x14][0xe0]![0xf7]o[0xe8]9[0xfa]S[0xb0]\[0xb9][0xa8][0x98]<[0xa2][0xd3][0x95][\n]"
10:18:29.899 [main] DEBUG org.apache.http.wire - http-outgoing-0 << ":1<[0x8f][0xa5]a[0xcb]-[0xd3][0x92][0xb3][0xf9][0x8b]g[0xd8][0xf4][0x91][0x87][0xfb]^[0x83][0xf5][0xfa]U[0x88][0x8c][0x96][0xec][0x1e][0xfd][0xcc][0xf2][0xff][0x0][0xc][0xf8][0xf9]G[0xb0][0x1f][0xc3][0xfc][0xea]Y[0xe6][0x8d][0x13]{8[0xda]z[0x1e][0xb9][0xfa]z[0xd5]XC#x[0xc4]ab[\n]"
10:18:29.899 [main] DEBUG org.apache.http.wire - http-outgoing-0 << "[0x10]p[0xa1]x[0x2][0xa9][0xce]|[0xd6]"[0xcf][0x2]q[0xc1][0x93][0xf8][0x17][0xeb][0xeb][0xf4][0x15][0x14][0x96][0xb3][0xcd]'[0x99][0x1e]m[0xe3][0xef][0x1e]pd[0xfa][0xe3][0xee][0x8f][0xf3][0xc5]X[0x8a]U[0x18][0x8b]o[0x94][0xc3][0x80][0x9d][0xbf][\n]"
10:18:29.899 [main] DEBUG org.apache.http.wire - http-outgoing-0 << "7[0x11][0x1d][0xbb]-[0xbb]bp|[0xf2]0eo[0xe2][0xfa]z[0xf]j[0xb3]-[0xc2]*[0xe1][0xf9][0xdc]8Q[0xc9]o[0xa0][0xaa][0xef]/[0x9e]Z(TI[0xd9][0x9d][0xbe][0xe2][0xff][0x0][0x89][0xf6][0x1f][0xa5]2+I,[0x1]e&p[0xdf]y[0x9b][0xef][0xfe][0x1e][0xde][0xd4][0x1][0xeb]w[0x9e][0x17][0xba][0xd5][0xa4][0x17][0x17]W[0x11]Z[0xb2][0x9d][0xdf]f[0xb5][0x7][0xcb][0x93][0xda]F<[0xb8][0xf6][0x0][0x3][0x9e]A[0xad];m@[0xc6][0xcb]k}[0x12][0xdb]J[0x6][0x14][0x8e]#a[0xec]{[0x9f][0xa5]Q[0xb8][0xf1]/[0xf6]5[0xca][0xd8][0xdf][0xa1][0xba][0x9d][0xb8][0x8c][0xdb][0x0][0xcc][0xde][0x1f][0xc3][0xef][0x9c]}[\r]Z[0xb9][0xb1][0xbf][0xd6][0xad][0xcc]wREem [0xfb][0xb6][0xe4]I.=D[0x84]a~[0xa0]~[0x15][0xc4]t[0x89][0xaa][0xdc][0xc5]36[0x9f][0x5][0xb2][0xdf]][0xe3]&2[0xdb]R[0x1c][0xff][0x0][0x14][0x8d][0xfc]?A[0xf3][0x1e][0xc2][0xb3][0xac]t[0x8b][0x8d][0x6]Suq+j[0x99][0x18]2[0xb2][0xe1][0xa0][0x1d][0xd5][0x7][0xf0][0xa7][0xeb][0xea]j[0xe5][0xa5][0x93][0xf8]b[0xdc][[0xc1][0x19][0x9b]ORO[0x1f]}3[0xd4][0x93][0xdf][0xea]J[0xbf].[0xa9]e[0x14][0xb]pg[0xc][0x1d][0xb6][0xa2] [0xdd]#[0xb7][0xf7]B[0x8e]I[0xf6][0xa0]C[0xa1][0xb8][0x86]x[0xbc][0xd8][0xa4][0x5][0x7]$[0xe7][0x1b]~[0xbe][0x95][0xce][0xde][0xc3]u[0xaa][0xca]e[0xf0][0xf3][0x8b]B[0xf][0xcf]|[0xcb][0xfb][0xb9]=U[0x17][0xf8][0x8f][0xfb]_w[0xea]jK[0x9f][0xe][0xde][0xea]3[0xb][0xe7][0xdb]j[0xa3][0x91][0xa6][0xab]f9[0xeb][0xa9][0x1c]1[0xff][0x0]g[0xee][0x8f][0xaf]5[0xb5]e}[0x1d][0xce]ad[0xf2]n#[0x18]h[[0x82]1[0xe9][0xed]@[0x14]4o[0xb3][0xc1][0xbe][0xdc][0xc2]a[0xbc]'3[0x19][0xe][0xe7][0x94][0xff][0x0]x[0xb1][0xe5][0xbf][0xa7]n*[0xc6][0xad][0x15][0x93]Z3[0xdf]2G[0x12][0xcb]RpT[0xfb]{[0xfb]w[0xa8]u[0x99]![0x9d][0xbe][0xc9]o[0x13]\[0xea]*7"[0xc6][0xdb]|[0x9f]Fv[0xfe][0x15][0xfa][0xf2]{[\n]"
10:18:29.899 [main] DEBUG org.apache.http.wire - http-outgoing-0 << "[0xa3][0xa7][0xc5]=[0xad][0xd2][0x1f][0x10]J[0xb7][0x17][0xa3][0xfd]M[0xc6]1[\n]"
10:18:29.899 [main] DEBUG org.apache.http.wire - http-outgoing-0 << "[0xff][0x0][0xb8][0xa7][0xee][0x9f][0xf6][0x8f]>[0xb8][0xe2][0x80]([0xc5]q[0xa9][0xcb]([0xb7][0xd4][0xc][0xf6]zcq[0x15][0xc0]][0xb3][0xcc]?[0xda][0xef][0x18][0xff][0x0][0xc7][0xbf][\n]"
10:18:29.899 [main] DEBUG org.apache.http.wire - http-outgoing-0 << "[0xe8]![0xb3][0xb6][0xb7][0xb6][0x16][0xf0]E[0x1a][0xc1][0x8e][0x11]G[0xca]s[0xdf][0xdf]>[0xbd][0xea][0xdc][0xd0][0xac][0xa8][0xd1][0xc8][0xa1][0xd5][0x87]*GZ[0xe5][0xa5][0xbd][0xbe][0xb5][0x98][0xc3][0xa3][0x8f][0xb4][0xd8][0x6]"k[0xa7][0x1b][0x92][0xdc][0xe7][0x90][0x9f][0xdf]?[0xa0][0xee]sL[0x9]5)[0xff][0x0][0xe1][0x1d][0x2]hKM[0x14][0x8d][0xc5][0x9a][0xfc][0xd2]1[0xff][0x0]`u?[0xd3][0xbd]-[0xba][0xc9][0xae]D&[0xb9]&[0xd8][0xf3][0xf6]8[0xdb][\r][0xf4][0x95][0x87][0xfe][0x82][0xbc]{[0x9a][0xd4][0xd3][0xac][0xad]cSs[0xb][0xb5][0xc4][0xd2][0x8f][0x9e][0xe6]C[0x99][0x1b][0xd8][0xff][0x0]t[0xb2]0[0x7][0xa5]s[0x1f][0x10]o[0xaf]|9`5-"[0x5]II"i[0x98][0xfc][0x8a];|[0xbd][0xd8][0x9f][0xc3][0xf1][0xa7]p0|m[0xe3]=?[0xc3]w[0xa9]k[0xa6][0xc0][0xa6][0xfa]%[0xc3][0x18][0xc8]T[0x8c]vR[0x7][0xb7]j[0xf3][0x1f][0x10][0xf8][0xbb]S[0xf1][0x19]A{(d[0x8c][0x92][0x8a][0xa3][0x0]VM[0xdd][0xdc][0xd7]s[0xc9]<[0xf2][0xb4][0xb2][0xc8][0xc5][0x9d][0xd8][0xe4][0x92]z[0x9a][0xac]Nk7!\S[0xea]i[0xa4][0xd0]i*I[\n]"

......
```

I couldn't post the full response as its to too large.

I have tried the following but it appears to be null:

```
HttpEntity httpEntity = httpResponse.getEntity();
String jsonResponse = EntityUtils.toString(httpEntity, StandardCharsets.UTF_8.name());
byte[] imageBytes = org.apache.commons.codec.binary.Base64.decodeBase64(jsonResponse);
BufferedImage img = ImageIO.read(new ByteArrayInputStream(imageBytes));
```

Comment: httpEntity.getContent() -> what does it returns? Is it just those hex values?

Comment: I get the following content: org.apache.http.conn.EofSensorInputStream@1f9e9475.  If I output just the httpentity, I get the following: httpEntity: ResponseEntityProxy{[Content-Type: image/jpeg,Content-Length: 20492,Chunked: false]}

Comment: Just as a side note, the image I am getting is from a video, so every time I call the api, I get a different image.  Hence the size difference between the different outputs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is the response a json String or is it just the jpeg bytes? If it's bytes then you shouldn't use a string.

My guess is something like:

```
HttpEntity httpEntity = httpResponse.getEntity();
BufferedImage img = ImageIO.read(httpEntity.getContent());
```

Comment: I have tried that and I still get a null image. ResponseEntityProxy{[Content-Type: image/jpeg,Content-Length: 25740,Chunked: false]}
img null

Comment: Thank you Lance Java, your solution does work, I was just being a plonker.  When I tried your solution, it was after the HttpResponse had been processed and closed. I have a class that makes the rest api calls, gets the data and stores the response, makes sure everything is closed and then passes the response data to the calling class which can then post process the data.  When I moved the code to where the HttpResponse was generated, I get the image.